# Bind an object with array variable

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, binding, datagrid

I know there are 100 questions about it, but I have not found an answer to this specific case.

I have an object that looks like this:

```
public string LogMessage { get; set; }
public DateTime Time { get; set; }        
public string[] Params { get; set; }
```

and I want to bind this object to datagrid (each object will be a row and each variable will be cell)

I tried to bind like this:

```
DataGridTextColumn Log = new DataGridTextColumn();
DataGridTextColumn Time = new DataGridTextColumn();
DataGridTextColumn Params = new DataGridTextColumn();
win.Table.Columns.Add(Time);
win.Table.Columns.Add(Log);
win.Table.Columns.Add(Params);
Time.Binding = new Binding("Time");
Log.Binding = new Binding("LogMessage");
Params.Binding = new Binding("Params");
```

But the result of the `Params` column is of course:"String[] Array".

I need to know if there is some option to manipulate the data after the bind. Something like:

```
new Binding("Params").ToJson();
```

Thanks!

Comment: remove all that code and create a proper ViewModel for this. then just bind the UI normally (**via XAML**) and not using procedural code.

Comment: I know this is the right way, but realy? there is no other options?

Comment: Because it's a small program and not really importance one.. so not optimal but easy solution would be enough

Comment: In a ListView GridView you could bind the array to a ComboBox or List.  Or create a property that just returns the array as a single concatenated text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are probably several ways to do this.  If you're able to change the class, then you could simply add a new property and bind to that:

```
public string[] ParamsString
{ 
    get { return string.Join(", ", Params); }
}
```

Alternatively, if you can't change the class, then you could create an `IValueConverter` that converts the array into the value you want.  For example:

```
public class ArrayToStringConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string[] input = value as string[];
        if (input != null && input.Length > 0)
            return string.Join(", ", input);
        return "";
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Now you can add the converter to the binding like this:

```
Params.Binding = new Binding("Params") { Converter = new ArrayToStringConverter() };
```